# FirebaseUI does not allow me to search for more than one using Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have an array of username(ids) which i need to search using Firebase Database and rendering using Firebase UI, the way that i am doing it is only showing the last user and not all of the users that have those ids. I need to render the cards or all the users with different ids.

This is my class

```
public class UserMessageListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private final String TAG = "UsersMessageList";
    private RecyclerView mResultList;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayUsers;

    public static UserMessageListFragment newInstance() {
        return new UserMessageListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_message_list, container, false);

        mResultList = view.findViewById(R.id.message_list);
        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mResultList.getContext()));

        final DatabaseReference refMessages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuarios");

        refMessages.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getKey().contains(UserDetails.username+ "_")) {
                    String[] userChatWithId = dataSnapshot.getKey().split(UserDetails.username+"_");
                    final Query firebaseSearchQuery = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userChatWithId[1]);
                    final FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options =
                            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                                    .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, User.class)
                                    .build();
                    bindAndBuildFirebaseUi(options);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
//        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
//        progressDialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
//        progressDialog.show();

        return view;
    }


    public void bindAndBuildFirebaseUi(FirebaseRecyclerOptions options) {
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_list_layout, parent, false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(v);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final UsersViewHolder holder, int position, final User model) {
                holder.bind(model);
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        UserDetails.chatWithId = model.getUsername();
                        UserDetails.chatWith = model.getName();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Chat.class));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

at this line

```
 final Query firebaseSearchQuery = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userChatWithId[1]);
```

there will be different values inside userChatWithid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW4JO.png), however FirebaseUI is rendering only the last one.

I am starting to hate FirebaseUI because i've been having so many issues with it.

Can anybody help me, please???

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some very unconventional stuff... FirebaseUI will handle all the database listeners and queries for you. All you should do is pass in the root node that contains all your users and the rest will be taken care of. (I believe in your case it's `usuarios` so `ref` will do the trick.) I'd recommend reading the docs: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: You didnt understand the problem. I need to take the users with the ids that are coming from  userChatWithId[1] which is a split from messages ids. Each message id is userId_chatwithid, iam trying to take ONLY the users with the ids that are coming from userChatWithId

Comment: I added a picture of a sample of my database. the first one are messages. The keys are formed by userId_chatWithAnotherUserID